# rails wkhtmltopdf-binary gem not render images from https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf

I am using `wkhtmltopdf-binary` gem in my rails application to convert the html pages to pdf and it was working(relative path) until I render the images from https(absolute path).

So it is working if the images are from the application and not working the images coming from http or https when export as pdf.

Is there any way I can get the images from external sites like `http, https`?

Answer (score 0):

The wkhtmltopdf binary is run outside of your Rails application; therefore, your normal layouts will not work. If you plan to use any CSS, JavaScript, or image files, you must modify your layout so that you provide an absolute reference to these files. The best option for Rails without the asset pipeline is to use the wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag, wicked_pdf_image_tag, and wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag helpers or to go straight to a CDN (Content Delivery Network) for popular libraries such as jQuery.

if you want to load images then you can do following

`<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag 'mysite.jpg' %>`

Check this link https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf